# Is += or -= in VBA possible?

Tags: vba

I have a really simple Question: Is there another option to `+=` or `-=` in `VBA`?

like:

> a += b

instead of:

> a = a + b

Thank you very much in advance for your answers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *compound assignment operators* (e.g. `+=`, `-=`) do not exist in VBA (which has a similar grammar to VB6, the precursor to VB.net).

You need to fall back to the equivalent `a = a + b`.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. This is MDSN link which shows VBA operators and expressions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1w3te48.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Public Sub Increment(ByRef value_to_increment, Optional l_plus As Long = 1)
    
    value_to_increment = value_to_increment + l_plus

End Sub

Public Sub Decrement(ByRef value_to_decrement, Optional l_minus As Long = 1)
    
    value_to_decrement = value_to_decrement - l_minus

End Sub
```

This is something that I am using daily. It somehow makes it easier for me. Usage is like this:

```
Call Increment(lValue)
```

Example of usage [here](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/2962e242158b8092d65a783227bfb210986558b5/IncrementDecrement.vb).